# Find source of mysterious ring tone sound on computer

Tags: windows-7, windows, audio

My computer is currently ringing like a telephone. It's like there is a telephone ringing! No programs that should be doing this are open. How can I determine what is causing the ringing?!

[image: Nothing suspicious in the Applications list.]

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to expand the Volume Mixer and see which particular application is making the sound.

[image: Windows Volume Mixer]